# Peering over a direct L2 link without IP addresses

Tags: blockchain, private-blockchain, peers

As part of a big solution incorporating blockchain and data networking, I'd like to know how would 2 nodes establish a blockchain peering on their direct L2 Ethernet Link that has no IP addresses configured?

In other words; is it possible to establish peering based on MAC addresses not IP addresses?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, node URL explicitly requires IP address.

> The hostname can only be given as an IP address, DNS domain names are
>   not allowed.

Source : https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/enode-url-format

Comment: Thank You! Is there any way one would change the code for a private chain to allow discovery and peering using L2 addresses instead of L3 addresses? (i.e. MAC addresses)

Comment: Do these hosts have IP at all ?  If yes, you can modify geth code to establish different means of connectivity (I.e./ to perform a arp and find out IP before connecting).

Comment: No the hosts don't have any IP connectivity between them. That is the point, I would like to allow blockchain discovery and peering to take place between them without IP addresses, solely based on L2 MAC addresses.

Comment: Do you have any software layer that can connect to hosts over L2 address and act as a socks proxy ?

Comment: Great suggestion, however I'm not sure how would that work around the need for IP addressing at all? We still need IP connectivity between the SOCKS server and the rest of the blockchain nodes, right?

Comment: Socks server would be local to blockchain node (can be on the same machine), so it can communicate over local ip.  Do machine have  TCP/IP network ?

Comment: Yes, this is a regular machine with normal TCP/IP stack. However I don't want to use IP addresses at all. I want all communications between machines to be on Layer-2 (i.e. Etherenet). I am sorry for making this conversation very long, I can't convert it to a chat due to my current reputation

Comment: In that case, modifying geth is the only option. I will see if I have some pointers on that.

Comment: Thanks. I'll be looking forward these pointers and your support.

Comment: I would start at https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/p2p/peer.go  and https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/p2p/netutil/net.go . These seem to be responsible to inbound and outbound connections.